# explicit formula for $ _2F_2(1,1;2;2;z) $

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is it an explicit formula for
$$ _2F_2(1,1;2;2;z) ,$$
where $$_2F_2(a,b;c;d;z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n(d)_n n!}z^n  .$$

thanks you in advance

Comment: I only see this function defined with 4 parameters here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: @Element118, OP's function is $_2F_2(1,1;2;2;z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(1)_n(1)_n}{(2)_n(2)_n n!}z^n$.

Comment: @eipi, any reference for that definition?

Comment: @Element118, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
_2F_2(1,1;2;2;z)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n!n!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!}\frac{z^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(n+1)(n+1)!}\\
&=\frac1z\int_0^z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{(n+1)!}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1z\int_0^z\frac{e^t-1}t\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
$$
This doesn't have a closed form without using special functions like the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) or [Incomplete Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: @ robjohn:  thank you for your answer